# Why I can use const char* as key in std::map<std::string, int>

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have define a data structure

```
std::map<std::string, int> a;
```

I found I can pass const char* as key, like this:

```
a["abc"] = 1;
```

Which function provides automatic type conversion from const char* to std::string?

Comment: Doing stuff like that implicitly sounds like a recipe for hard to find bugs.

Comment: Nah, some implicit conversions are fine. A C-string and `std::string` are semantically equivalent, it's just that a C string is a useless piece of crap.

Comment: @Warren, it's common in C++, especially for commonly used constructs like std::string.  You can enjoy the performance hit of the temporary std::string construction every time you do a lookup though...

Comment: Yet another C++ slippery slope argument.   I guess I'm still twitching from the last time that bit me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`std::string` has a [constructor that allows the implicit conversion from `const char*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

means that an implicit conversion such as

```
std::string s = "Hello";
```

is allowed.

It is the equivalent of doing something like

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo() {}
  Foo(int) {} // implicit converting constructor.
};

Foo f1 = 42;
Foo f2;
f2 = 33 + 9;
```

If you wanted to disallow the implicit conversion construction, you mark the constructor as `explicit`:

```
struct Foo 
{
  explicit Foo(int) {}
};

Foo f = 33+9; // error
Foo f(33+9); // OK
f = Foo(33+9); // OK
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a constructor for std::string which takes const char* as a parameter.

```
string::string(const char*);
```

Unless the constructor is declared explicit then the compiler will apply one use defined conversion if needed to call any function.

Answer (score 3):

See [string constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/). The constructor provides the conversion for the key in your map. It's equivalent to

```
a[std::string("abc")] = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++ if you make a class constructor that only takes one parameter, then (unless you tell it otherwise with `explicit`), that parameter's type will be [implicitly convertable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Implicit_type_conversion) to your class.

`std::string` has such a constructor for `char *`

Yes, this can cause some unexpected behavior on occasion. This is why you generally should put `explicit` on single-parameter constructors, unless you really want these silent conversions.