# Why a simple bimap ( std::string <-> int) does not work?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

A puzzling question to C++ template and type conversion is shown below...
To make my life easier, I defined a template class to model a one-to-one relationship using a class BiMap:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <map>   
#include <string>

template<class T1, class T2>
class BiMap {
 public:
  T2& operator[] (T1& t1) {
    return d1[t1];
  }
  T1& operator[] (T2& t2) {
    return d2[t2];
  }
 private:
  std::map<T1, T2> d1;
  std::map<T2, T1> d2;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  BiMap<std::string, int> m;
  m["1"] = 2;
  m[2] = 3;

  printf("%d", m["1"]);
  printf("%d", m[2]); 
  return 0;     
}
```

But I get this compiling error:

```
testPedigree.cpp:45: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘m["1"]’
testPedigree.cpp:16: note: candidates are: T2& BiMap<T1, T2>::operator[](T1&) [with T1 = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, T2 = int]
testPedigree.cpp:19: note:                 T1& BiMap<T1, T2>::operator[](T2&) [with T1 = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, T2 = int]
```

I was expecting C++ will automatically cast const char* to std::string, as I asked the question in this post: [Why I can use const char* as key in std::map<std::string, int>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725873/why-i-can-use-const-char-as-key-in-stdmapstdstring-int)

Comment: I'm not sure this will do what you want it to. It will store the results forwards and backwards, but you won't be able to look up the reversed results. So, if you do `b[4] = "Hi";`, `b["Hi"]` will not return `4`. Not sure if this is what you want or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code tries to bind a non-`const` reference to a temporary (namely, the `std::string` which is implicitly created from your `const char[]`). Only `const` references can be bound to temporaries.

Try:

```
  T2& operator[] (const T1& t1) {
    return d1[t1];
  }
  T1& operator[] (const T2& t2) {
    return d2[t2];
  }
```

You have some other trivial bugs in your sample. Here is a corrected, tested program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>

template<class T1, class T2>
class BiMap {
 public:
  T2& operator[] (const T1& t1) {
    return d1[t1];
  }
  T1& operator[] (const T2& t2) {
    return d2[t2];
  }
 private:
  std::map<T1, T2> d1;
  std::map<T2, T1> d2;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  BiMap<std::string, int> m;
  m["1"] = 2;
  m[2] = "3";

  printf("%d", m["1"]);
  printf("%s\n", m[2].c_str());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, consider changing `printf("%d", m[2]);` to `printf("%s", m[2].c_str());`

Comment: Yep. Also `m[2] = 3;` seems like a lose.